# Display iphone application settings within your application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

The iphone supports a means of defining your application's settings such that it will automatically create a UI in the Settings app. I want to also allow the user to edit the application settings within the application but it'd be nice to reuse the same UI that is automatically created.

See: [Application Settings](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ApplicationSettings/ApplicationSettings.html)

Is there a way to have your application display the settings using the same UI that the Settings application does?

Comment: not that I know of, but I would be interested in this as well!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No there is not a way to reuse the UI.

There is, however, a way to reuse the data.  Settings.app will put the settings in NSUserDefaults under the keys specified in your Settings.bundle plist file.  You can alter those values in your app, then switch to Settings.app and see that it will have changed to reflect your new values.  This is really nice if you want to allow the user to edit settings in the app (if that's what they're used to) or in Settings.app (if that's what they're used to).

**EDIT #1**

You may want to look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1203266/how-to-simplify-in-app-application-settings-management). There is a library called [mySettings](http://blog.nottoobadsoftware.com/2009/03/mysettings-a-settings-api-for-the-iphone/) that would make building this easier.

**EDIT #2**

There are a couple libraries available now that do this:

- [InAppSettings](http://bitbucket.org/keegan3d/inappsettings/wiki/Home)
- [InAppSettingsKit](http://www.inappsettingskit.com/)