# How can you launch a URL from the iOS Settings Bundle?

Tags: iphone, ios4, settings, bundle, settings.bundle

I would like to launch a URL from the iOS Settings Bundle that would at least launch Safari when they Touched the setting.

Not sure if this is possible I couldn't find any examples of this in the Settings area with Apple or 3rd party apps. If it is not I would appreciate confirmation for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Current Settings.bundle is able to **only display or change values**. Better check Apple docs [Settings Application Schema Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/PreferenceSettings/Conceptual/SettingsApplicationSchemaReference/Articles/RootContent.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007018-SW1) and the few available element types. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

The Twitter Preferences show up with a link "Learn More about Twitter" to navigate to twitter.com (Safari).
I could not figure out how they did it but it seems to be possible.

Answer (score 1):

I was searching for the same UI experience "a button in the settings page" to allow the user to reset some settings, I found this http://inappsettingskit.com/ .

As others said it's not possible to do in apples Settings.app, so the solution in to implement an in-app settings page, this open source project seems to make it easy. I'll update after I implement.

(I have no connection to this project)

Comment: Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/47288542/1018394 for the plist changes required

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if that is possible. This previous SO question [Display iphone application settings within your application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1141391/display-iphone-application-settings-within-your-application) says something about using them within the app. See if it helps.
Another SO question that can be of use [Programmatically opening the settings app (iPhone)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736047/programmatically-opening-the-settings-app-iphone)

Comment: Yeah I read those before posting they are not related to what I want to do.  Using a URL from within your own App is easy and how to launch the settings and other apps.  However I want to launch a URL from the Settings Bundle but couldn't see any of the limited functionality it provided that would do that.  I am pretty sure it can't be done with the current iOS version. Thanks though.

Comment: You wouldn't want people to people to access your app to do their custom actions. Would you? I guess the same goes for Apple too.. So i guess its not possible. Do let me know if you come across something on this.