# How to Open a URL in Safari from settings.bundle

Tags: xcode, settings.bundle

How can I open a URL in Safari from Settings?

Something like in the [Nike+ App](https://photos-6.dropbox.com/t/0/AABLnKrfHeZuGIIKE4Ov6P1A52tWzEGaaVW9ZE2RFyw8yg/12/113028400/png/1024x768/3/1395205200/0/2/IMG_0449.PNG/8hYnodykHS1lWBDnItDGLNVq1oWiIaoNziHhPO4z-Io)

Does it need to be customized? I can't seem to find a Type for adding a URL in the Root.plist.

Comment: Refer this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5959274/how-can-you-launch-a-url-from-the-ios-settings-bundle

Comment: refer this url.. hope this may help you http://digdog.tumblr.com/post/490664298/ddopenurlspecifier

Answer (score 0):

you can check out this on git https://github.com/futuretap/InAppSettingsKit

then put this value into the plist

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>DefaultValue</key>
    <string>inappsettingskit.com</string>
    <key>File</key>
    <string>http://www.inappsettingskit.com/</string>
    <key>Title</key>
    <string>Open URL</string>
    <key>Type</key>
    <string>IASKOpenURLSpecifier</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Mind you, this only makes it possible to open URL's from a Settings page shown inside the app.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to GSiklos's answer abouve, but using the plist editor in XCode , the change would be:

[image: PList Editor Example]

Note that as default, any URL's shown in the IASK settings are NOT displayed in the standard iOS settings page (usefully)